# How to display next data set if data already found in table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display unanswered survey questions to user. If he already answered the question, I want to display next unanswered question.

```
            <?php 
             $i=1; 
             $surveyQ = "SELECT * FROM ve_survey_answers a 
             INNER JOIN ve_survey_questions q 
             ON a.QuestionId = q.id
             ORDER BY a.QuestionId
             LIMIT 4";
             $surveyResult = mysqli_query($db, $surveyQ);
             $question = "";
             while ($survey=mysqli_fetch_array($surveyResult)){$i++;
             $curr_question = $survey['Question'];
             $curr_questionid = $survey['QuestionId'];
             //check if user has already answered question
             $answeredquestions=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT QuestionId FROM ve_survey_useranswers a JOIN ve_users u ON a.UserId=u.UserID WHERE a.QuestionId='$curr_questionid' AND u.ProfileName = '$user_check'");
             if ($question != $curr_question && $answeredquestions->num_rows == 0) {
             $question = $curr_question;
             echo "<h5 style='font-weight: bold;'>$question</h5>";
             }
             elseif($question != $curr_question && $answeredquestions->num_rows > 0) {
             //display an unanswered question
             $surveyQ = "SELECT * FROM ve_survey_answers a 
             INNER JOIN ve_survey_questions q 
             ON a.QuestionId = q.id
             WHERE q.id <> $curr_questionid
             ORDER BY a.QuestionId LIMIT 4";
             $surveyResult = mysqli_query($db, $surveyQ);
             }
             ;?>
    <div class="div">
    <input type="radio" name="useranswer" id="radio<?=$i;?>" class="radio" 
    value='<?=$survey['AnswerId'];?>'/>

    <label class="surveylabel" for="radio<?=$i;?>"><?=$survey['Answer'];?>
    </label>
    </div>
   <?php } ;?>
```

The code I wrote displays as follow:

```
Cat// data from the previous question
If you could reincarnate into an animal, which animal would it be?
Sloth
Tiger
Meerkat
Blue Whale
```

Cat is not supposed to be there. It is one of the answers from previous question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `if - elseif` in `while` is problematic. You've changed the query via `$surveyQ`. However, `$survey` variable still contains old result set. You might want to reset `$survey` variable to an empty array and check if it contains anything before printing `$survey['AnswerId']` or `$survey['Answer']`

Comment: @DhruvSaxena: I havent thought of that. How would you present the code?

Comment: When you populate `$surveyQ` with a new query inside `elseif`, you could reset `$survey` as `$survey = array();`. Also, before creating `<div class="div">` (i.e. radio button and label), you could check: `if(isset($survey['AnswerId']))` and if that turns out to be true, only then show the radio button. Does that help?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena: It's almost working... but then I get an undefined variable instead of Cat.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena: the undefined index is Answer

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code around and it works:

```
        <?php 
        $i=1; 
        //check user answers
         $surveyanswerQ = "SELECT * FROM ve_survey_useranswers ORDER BY QuestionId";
         $surveyanswerResult = mysqli_query($db, $surveyanswerQ);
         $surveyanswer=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($surveyanswerResult);
         //select all questions
        $surveyQ = "SELECT * FROM ve_survey_questions q JOIN ve_survey_answers a ON q.id=a.QuestionId WHERE q.id <> {$surveyanswer['QuestionId']} ORDER BY a.QuestionId LIMIT 4 ";
         $surveyResult = mysqli_query($db, $surveyQ);
         $question = "";
         while ($survey=mysqli_fetch_array($surveyResult)){$i++;
           $curr_question = $survey['Question'];
         $curr_questionid = $survey['id'];
          if ($question != $curr_question) {
         $question = $curr_question;
         echo "<h5 style='font-weight: bold;'>$question</h5>";
         }
        ;?>
       <div class="div">
       <input type="radio" name="useranswer" id="radio<?=$i;?>" class="radio" value='<?=$survey['AnswerId'];?>'/>
       <label class="surveylabel" for="radio<?=$i;?>"><?=$survey['Answer'];?></label>
       </div>
```